# Mock elastic client call

Tags: c#, moq, nest

I'm trying to `Moq` call to  elastic client, but it doesn't work.

I have this call inside by generic `repo.Update(T doc)`:

```
var response = await _client.UpdateAsync(DocumentPath<T>.Id(doc),
     d => d
       .Upsert(doc)
       .Script(.....)
);
```

In my test I want to verify if `UpdateAsync` was called with those specific inputs.

I tried the following which didn't work:

```
_mock = new Mock<IElasticClient>();

Func<UpdateDescriptor<Document,Document>, 
    IUpdateRequest<Document,Document>> sel = d => d.Upsert(doc).Script(....);

await repo.Update(document)

_mock.Verify(c => c.UpdateAsync<Document>(
     It.Is<DocumentPath<Document>(
        docPath => docPath == DocumentPath<Document>.Id(document),
     It.Is<Func<...>(s => s == sel),
     it.IsAny<CancellationToken>()
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have problem with first verification condition:

```
docPath => docPath == DocumentPath<Document>.Id(document)
```

As you can see in [NEST source code](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/master/src/Nest/CommonAbstractions/Infer/DocumentPath/DocumentPath.cs), `DocumentPath` class doesn't overload == operator - it checks reference equality.
DocumentPath.Id(document) creates new object so the condition is always false.

Hope that helps.